# Attach Current Build to Test

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

I'm playing around with Microsoft Test Manager 2013 (though it appears it is just MTM2012) to try and get a better understanding of test cases and test suites as I want to use this at work. So I was hoping that I could run a test suite on a build which gets included in this test suite. That is what I *WANT* to do, but it could very well be wrong. So maybe a better scope of what I'm doing at work might lend to a better answer.

My company makes tablet PC's. I write programs for those tablets. For sake of argument lets just say there are 5 tablets, that run a similar array of OS's. Tablet1,2,3 and 4 can run WinXP, WinXP embedded, Win7, and Win7 Embeded, and Tablet5 can run Win7, Win7 Embedded, and Win8 embedded. Lets say i'm making a Display test program. Naturally this display test will run differently on each tablet, but the program it self is supposed to be able to handle that along with not being able to worry about OS. So I wrote out a very simple test. Open Program, try to open again, verify only 1 instance, check display, close program.

I figured it would be good to make a Test Suite called "Complete Display Program Test" and put 5 sub test suites to that for each tablet. Then moved the 5 test cases to a single test suite. I configured all test cases to only have the correct tablet/OS configuration. Queued a build and waited for it to finish. I then attached that build to the main test suite. I then clicked on run a test for tablet 1 but I didn't see the build attached to the test runner. I've looked around a little bit to see why or how and haven't found anything. Question is is how do I do that? Or if you are scratching your head and wondering why in the world I am doing it this way then by all means suggest another way. This is the second time I have ever looked into MTM so I might not be doing it right.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you have the time, out this pretty solid overview for MTM: http://www.codemag.com/article/1103013

Comment: I would also recommend this free e-book: [Testing for Continuous Delivery with Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35380)

Answer (score 1):

When running manual tests from *MTM* you will not see the build you are using in *Test Runner*.

But if you complete the test and set the test outcome you will be able to check which build you've ran the test against.

Just double-click on the test or select "View Results" to display test results:

[image]

This column is not visible by default. You will have to right-click on the column row and select the column "Buld number" to be displayed.

You will also be able to see the build number in "Analyse Test Runs" area:

[image]

**The things are slightly different if you are running automated test.**
Consider following approach:

1. Automate your *Test Cases*
   See [How to: Associate an Automated Test with a Test Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.
2. Create a *Build Definition* building your application under test **AND** assemblies containing your tests.
   I strongly recommend build application you want to test and test assemblies using in the same *Build Definition*. (You will see why a little bit later).
3. Run this build definition and deploy the latest version of the application to the environment where you want run the tests.
   This is **very important to understand**: if you run automated tests the **tests assemblies only  would be deployed automatically** to the environment.
   It's your job to deploy the right version of the application you are going to test.
4. Now you can run tests from *MTM*.
   You can do it the way described by @AndrewClear in the comment to this answer: *"choose "Run with Options" when you're beginning a test run"* and select the latest build.
   Now test assemblies containing tests which are using to automate *Test Cases* will be deployed automatically to the test environment and the tests will be executed.
   That is the point you should recognize why is it so important to build application and tests with a single *Build Definition*: since the build number you've just selected when starting the tests will be stored along with the test results on TFS you will later know what version of you application you were testing (assuming you deployed the right version, of course).

**You could go a little bit further if you want even more automation** (This is the way I'm currently running automated tests)
Use Deploy-Build-Test template (this is a good place to start reading about [Setting Up Automated Build-Deploy-Test Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191495%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
Using this approach you will be able to automate deployment of the application you want to test.

Comment: How do I get the build for testing though? Who's to say I grabbed Build 4 when I'm testing against Build 3?

Comment: There isn't a automatic verification to determine which build you're testing against, just a manual configuration. To change it at run time, choose "Run with Options" when you're beginning a test run.

Comment: Like @Andrew said, the build number you selected before running **manual** test is just "for the record". Basically, it's a possibility for you do store this information along with the whole Test Run and Test Results for single Test Cases into TFS. There is no automatic verification behind. Although, if you run an **automated** Test Case this build number specifies the build which drop location should be used to (automatically) take the **test** to run. Note, also in this case **you** have to make sure the right build of the application under test is deployed.

Comment: So it looks like I should consider writing some automated because that will use the correct build automatically. Interesting. I was thinking about automated tests this morning since many of my tests are things like "Open program, Press @Button on keyboard: Expected Calc.exe to open" "Open program, change configuration, examine config file: Expect change was made in config file". If this is correct can you add that to your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I've just extended my answer. Let me know if something is still unclear.