# Run CodedUI from MTM 2013

Tags: testing, tfs, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I want to run a codedUI test case using MTM 2013

Here is what I already have so far:

1. I have codedUI test cases to test my web application.
2. The solution of these test cases has got nothing to do with my web application.
3. Now I have few test cases written in MTM 2013 (initially for manual execution). Later I had plan to automate these Test Cases Using codedUI and associate these automated Test cases to MTM test cases so that I don't have to open VSTS to run my automated test cases. Also this may serve the purpose that any other tester can also execute them using MTM.

Here is all I have done so far:

1. Installed and configured "Test Controller" in my TFS server.
2. Installed "Test Agent" on the machine I want to execute the automated test cases.
3. Created Physical Lab Environment successfully in MTM.
4. Associated the codedUI automation with test cases in MTM.

Now when I go to play test case in MTM, it gives me an error "**Cannot create automated test run.  A build associated with the active test plan is required to submit an automated test run.**"

Can you please help me with this. This is the first time I am using MTM test cases to associate codedUI automated test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a build to your test plan that contains your Coded UI tests. Otherwise, how does it know which version of your tests to run, and which version of your coded is being tested?

MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490760(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490760%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: In addition you should have the project that contains the CodedUI tests in the same solution as your main application under test. This will make it easyer to do build->deploy->test.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answers to following SO questions, they may help you to understand how it is working:

- [Couldn't run my test using Microsoft Test Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033217/couldnt-run-my-test-using-microsoft-test-manager/20056016#20056016)
- [Attach Current Build to Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368904/attach-current-build-to-test/20376712#20376712)