# Files not copied from drop folder to QTAgent when run Test Manger

Tags: c#, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, TFS 2012, Test Controller 2012, Test Agent 2012, Test manager 2012.

I made a build in TFS and set output to shared directory '`\\bdi-04\Test`'. then configure controller on TFS and agent on controller, create machine on Lab center.

But when try to run test on Test Manager I got this error:

> Invalid program name: 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTAgent\931\V-MAREF-LAP.middleeast.corp.microsoft.com\Deployment\ConsoleTest.exe'.

What is missing for me?

I tried to copy output from shared directory '`\\bdi-04\Test`' to next expected generated folder in `QTAgent` which will be '`.....Local\VSEQT\QTAgent\932\V-MAREF-LAP.middleeast.corp.microsoft.com\Deployment\`'
Then it worked.

How to make Agent copy needed files from drop location to `QTAgent` and use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your replies.

finally i cached the problem.

because i  set the output files on shared directory \bdi-04\Test, then i should add output directory to Deployment in Test Settings, see my post on msdn:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ff532bb-3540-467b-a47b-1c9114f45c6c/files-not-copied-from-drop-folder-to-qtagent-when-run-test-manger?forum=netfxsetup

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must select a build definition that has the correct build drop location for your existing automated test assemblies.

Please check this article for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#TestPlan.

My answer to this SO question may be helpful for you as well: [Attach Current Build to Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368904/attach-current-build-to-test).